# Async issue in discord bot code; Unexpected Token (

Tags: javascript, bots, discord.js

I wanted to start my bot but the console is giving me the `SyntaxError : Unexpected token (`.

A few months ago the code worked just fine, now it keeps giving me this error:

```
    bot.on("ready", async () => {
                          ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

I tried removing the async keywords completely in my code but now I get another error:

```
console.log(` `);
SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

```
bot.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(` `);
    console.log(` `);
    console.log(`============================================`);
    console.log(` `);
    console.log('     The bot is now fully opertational!')
    console.log(` `);
    console.log(`============================================`);
});
```

I expect the ouput to be *"The bot is now fully operational"*.

Comment: add the code into your post.

Comment: You don't need the `async` keyword if you're not `await`ing anything inside this function.

Comment: That code is syntactically valid per any online syntax validation tool. Try making sure you are running an up to date version of nodejs (should be V10 or higher).

Also not sure why you are printing whitespace in console like that...

Comment: Check what version of node.js you are running by running the command node -v, there isn't support for await/async until node 8. Removing the async should work, post the code you are running with the async removed.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
bot.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log(` `);
    console.log(` `);
    console.log(`============================================`);
    console.log(` `);
    console.log('     The bot is now fully opertational!')
    console.log(` `);
    console.log(`============================================`);
})
```

This should work :)